# How do I display subcategories in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I've just started working with Joomla recently and something I thought would be easy is proving to be quite difficult. Not sure if I'm retarded or if it's just more difficult than it needs to be.

I'm trying to create a footer menu that displays the parent category 'products' along with all the subcategories (children) of the parent category. For some reason I can't figure it out.

Google is failing me, can someone please point me in the right direction? Much obliged.

Comment: If it's a meu you just need to create menu liks for each of the subcategories. You could however switch to the categories module whihc gives you tons of options without having to make menu items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you won't be able to do something like this out of the box.

But there's nothing a Joomla extension won't do :)

Take a look at this one - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/drop-a-tab-menus/163